# WinUI3 XAML Master-Detail View Binding for Different Types

Tags: c#, binding, desktop, winui-3

I'm Stuck creating a Master/Detail View in WinUI 3.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WiYc.png)

I Have a treeview as my master list with two different item types
ExplorerItemTypeA and ExplorerItemTypeA each a partial class from the base ExplorerItem

I wish for the detail view to show the correct template for the different type (A&B) so I can bind and edit etc.

The Treeview DataTemplates work fine. Here is the XAML for the details view:

```
<Page.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTypeATemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItemTypeA">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="A Template"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTypeBTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItemTypeB">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="B Template"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ExplorerContentTemplateSelector x:Key="ExplorerContentTemplateSelector" 
                                        TreeItemTypeATemplate="{StaticResource ContentTypeATemplate}" 
                                        TreeItemTypeBTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTypeBTemplate}"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

If first tried a frame but am now trying a Content presenter for the detail view.

```
     <TreeView x:Name="MasterListView" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.TemplateItems}"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExplorerItemTemplateSelector}"/>

    <ContentPresenter
        x:Name="DetailContentPresenter"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Content="{x:Bind MasterListView.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExplorerContentTemplateSelector}" />
```

The Selector is

```
    public class ExplorerContentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TreeItemTypeATemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TreeItemTypeBTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        var explorerItem = (ExplorerItem)item;
        switch (explorerItem.Type)
        {
            case ExplorerItem.ExplorerItemType.A:
                return TreeItemTypeATemplate;
            case ExplorerItem.ExplorerItemType.B:
                return TreeItemTypeBTemplate;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                return TreeItemTypeATemplate;
        }

    }
}
```

I feel the answer is obvious and elegant, but despite searching for clues and methods this c# beginner is just not getting anywhere.
I've been stuck on this simple problem for far longer than I care to admit.

Thanks to anyone who is willing to give their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `ContentPresenter` with a `ContentControl` in your XAML markup:

```
<ContentControl
    x:Name="DetailContentPresenter"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Content="{x:Bind MasterListView.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExplorerContentTemplateSelector}" />
```

In your `DataTemplateSelector`, you should also override the `SelectTemplateCore` overload that accepts a `DependencyObject` parameter:

```
public class ExplorerContentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TreeItemTypeATemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TreeItemTypeBTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item) =>
        SelectTemplateCore(item, null);

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var explorerItem = item as ExplorerItem;
        switch (explorerItem?.Type)
        {
            case ExplorerItem.ExplorerItemType.A:
                return TreeItemTypeATemplate;
            case ExplorerItem.ExplorerItemType.B:
                return TreeItemTypeBTemplate;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                return TreeItemTypeATemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much for your time. No way I would have found that out. I'll do some further research into the TemplateSelectors & SelectTemplateCore. Cheers

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.selecttemplatecore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.selecttemplatecore)
If your ItemsControl.ItemsPanel is an ItemsStackPanel or ItemsWrapGrid, provide an override for the SelectTemplateCore(Object) method. If the ItemsPanel is a different panel, such as VirtualizingStackPanel or WrapGrid, provide an override for the SelectTemplateCore(Object, DependencyObject) method.